# How to sync Yosemite Photos library to Synology Diskstation?

Tags: data-synchronization, photos

I'd like to know if anyone has found a way to sync the new Photos app on Yosemite with a Synology diskstation. I know backing up is easily done either using Time Machine or another app, but I want to sync the 'Events' of Photos to my Diskstation to allow for it to index the files to the built in Photo Station application on the NAS.

Answer (score 1):

I'm doing that with [Phoshare](https://code.google.com/p/phoshare/).

I'm using automator for running an apple script when my iMac starts. This script calls phoshare to sync my events with the NAS.

The apple script look like:

```
cd /Applications/Phoshare-1.5.2.app/Contents/MacOS
./Phoshare \
  --export "/Volumes/photo/2015" \
  --iphoto "/Users/toto/Pictures/iPhoto Library.photolibrary" \
  -e ".*2015" \
  --foldertemplate "{mm}-{name}" \
  --nametemplate "{title}" \
  --captiontemplate "{description}" \
  -u -d -f -K --gps
```

Comment: This seems more like a shell script than an apple script.